# I can't get my javascript counter to work correctly

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to work on timer for my website b/w two date ( now date and my cdate input) please i would like someone to help me out with my code

```js
function ctimer() {
 var cdate = new Date("2017-03-31 13:06:57");
 var now = new Date();
 var timeDiff = cdate.getTime() - now.getTime();
 if (timeDiff <= 0) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
  
        }
 var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
 var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
 var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
 var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);


 document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days;
 document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours;
 document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes;
 document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = seconds;
 var timer = setTimeout('ctimer()',1000);
}
```

```html
<span id="daysBox"></span>
Days
<span id="hoursBox"></span>
Hrs:
<span id="minsBox"></span>
Min:
<span id="secsBox"></span>
Sec

<script>ctimer();</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout('ctimer()',1000)` should be `setTimeout(ctimer,1000)`. It takes a function not a string.

Comment: Your timer var needs to be global to the function otherwise your cleartimeout won't work

Comment: Replace `setTimeout('ctimer()',1000);` with `setTimeout(ctimer,1000);`

Comment: You can see for full working example of countdown at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this after the day variable

```
var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
hours %= 24;
minutes %= 60;
seconds %= 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forget the `%` to get only remaining values of minute , seconde and hours

```js
function ctimer() {
 var cdate = new Date("2017-04-31 13:06:57");
 var now = new Date();
 var timeDiff = cdate.getTime() - now.getTime();

 var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
 var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
 var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
 var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);


 
 var timer = setTimeout('ctimer()',1000);
        if (timeDiff <= 0) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = (days);
     document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = (hours%24);
     document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = (minutes%60);
     document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = (seconds%60);
}

ctimer()
```

```html
<h2>reamaining time to 2017-06-31 13:06:57 is :</h2>
<span id="daysBox"></span>
Days
<span id="hoursBox"></span>
Hrs:
<span id="minsBox"></span>
Min:
<span id="secsBox"></span>
Sec
```

Comment: Have you tried the snippet !!! , I see no error ? , and  do you know that 
`clearTimeout('undefined');` return undefined and dont throw any error !

Comment: yes , it carry on counting and it'll show negative values !  you mean here that that block if is useless , so I agree , but if he want to show only if date is > to today , just place that block after settimout declaration ,

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things changed

- dont pass a string to `setTimeout`
- calculate days/hrs/mins/secs *remaining* with use of modulo
- Make `timer` global, otherwise it wont stop counting down.

```js
var timer;
function ctimer() {
 var cdate = new Date("2017-06-31 13:06:57");
 var now = new Date();
 var timeDiff = cdate.getTime() - now.getTime();
 if (timeDiff <= 0) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
  
        }
 var days = Math.floor(timeDiff / (24*60*60*1000))
 var hours = Math.floor(timeDiff / (60*60*1000)) % 24;
 var minutes = Math.floor(timeDiff / (60*1000)) % 60;
 var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000) % 60;


 document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days;
 document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours;
 document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes;
 document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = seconds;
 timer = setTimeout(ctimer,1000);
}
ctimer();
```

```html
<span id="daysBox"></span>
Days
<span id="hoursBox"></span>
Hrs:
<span id="minsBox"></span>
Min:
<span id="secsBox"></span>
Sec
```